# saving images from galleria component of primefaces with javascript

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

i'm using jsf 2.2 primefaces 6.0 and i have already implemented a solution to display images with galleria primefaces component.The issue now is i'm triying to find solution to download the images from galleria through a button using javascript.(remarque i'm a beginner programmer and never used js)

One of stackoverflow members give me a code but it doesn't work or i was unable to implement it.

Here the xhtml code:

```
<p:galleria value="#{demandeBean.demandeSelectionnee.images}" 
                        panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="false"
                        autoPlay="false" var="image">
                        <p:graphicImage
                            value="http://localhost:18080/openCars/images/#{image}"
                            width="500" height="313" />
                    </p:galleria>
```

Here the proposed solution with js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download() {
    $('.ui-galleria-panel img').each(function() {
   $(this).after( "<a href='"+ $(this).attr('src') +"' download='nameOfImage.jpg' class='ui-button' style='position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0; padding: 5px 10px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>" )
});
</script>
```

Comment: _" but it doesn't work or i was unable to implement it."_ this is like an end-user describing the problem. Approach it like a developer. What is happening, do you see the buttons appearing? Is the function called? Please narrow down the problem. Way to broad/unclear now without us asking for all kinds of clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your `p:graphicImage` inside a `p:commandLink`

```
<p:galleria value="#{demandeBean.demandeSelectionnee.images}" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="false"
                        autoPlay="false" var="image">
   <p:commandLink action="#{demandeBean.download(image.id)}">
      <p:graphicImage value="http://localhost:18080/openCars/images/#{image}" width="500" height="313" />
   </p:commandLink>
</p:galleria>
```

Comment: Then you get a second call to the server (and what does the download(...) actually do?) The javascript code in the question would retrieve it from the cache (if implemented correctly)

Comment: actually one of stackoverflow member proposed my this solution and it's work fine on my application.I just have knowledge on JSF components and java.I have no idea on JS

Answer (score 0):

(Here the working solution) : At each galleria component there is a download button attached in order to download each image displayed.

This solution is very easy to implement just add the JavaScript code and an command on the galleria component as follow:

Here xhtml code of the galleria:

```
<p:dialog header="Documents numérisés" widgetVar="diag" modal="true"
                dynamic="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true"
                position="center" id="diagImages" onShow="download()">
                <p:outputPanel id="gal" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:galleria value="#{demandeBean.demandeSelectionnee.images}"
                        panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="false"
                        autoPlay="false" var="image">
                        <p:graphicImage
                            value="http://localhost:18080/openCars/images/#{image}"
                            width="500" height="313" />
                    </p:galleria>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
```

Here the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function download() {
            $('.ui-galleria-panel img').each(function() {
                   $(this).after( "<a href='"+ $(this).attr('src') +"' download='Documents numérisés.jpg' class='ui-button' style='position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0; padding: 5px 10px;background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);'><i class='fa fa-download'></i></a>" )
                });
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
```

Here the supposed result in pictures:
[[image: Galleria with download button]]